# Read/Write protection of script

Tags: security

I have a script file (.m), which I need to distribute for execution. How can I read/write protect it? thanks

Comment: See [Encode](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Encode.html).

Comment: ah...it works exactly the way I want. thanks. I guess there is not issue with running encoded .m files from command line. Also, still not sure, if a .m file encoded and distributed, can be decoded by others? For instance, see the definition of Encode[]: <<dest
decodes the file before reading its contents.